# Printing std::u8stream in std::ostream and a concept for checking it

Tags: c++, string, c++20, iostream, concept

In the codebase I have to support there is a concept checking that some type can be printed in output stream:

```
template <typename T>
concept OstreamFormattable = requires( const T& t, std::ostream& out ) {
    { out << t } -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream&>;
};
```

and there is also a user defined overload of `operator <<` for `std::u8string`:

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream & s, const std::u8string & str ) {
  return s << std::string( str.begin(), str.end() );
}
```

And `OstreamFormattable<std::u8string>` always evaluates to `true` in Visual Studio, but in GCC/Clang it is so only if `operator <<` is declared before the concept, and `false` if it is declared later. Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jM317xq7P

Is it a bug of Visual Studio compiler? Is it possible to fix the concept or `operator<<` declaration to work in all compilers independently on the order of their inclusion?

Comment: Looks like MSVC bug; it doesn't implement two-phase lookup correctly. `operator<<` should be looked up at the point of definition (where your overload is not found because it hasn't been seen yet) and again at the point of instantiation using argument-dependent lookup only (where it's not found because it's in global namespace but both arguments are in `std`). If we put the operator into namespace `std`, [the example works](https://godbolt.org/z/KdqTP8PY9) with all three compilers. But that's technically illegal - adding overloads to `std` that don't involve user-defined types.